# How does one concat the results of angularjs jqlite find?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, concatenation, jqlite

I am working on a directive that is going to disable all form elements on the page based on a rootScope variable (similar to adding ng-disabled to every item manually, but just a more convenient way.  I'm reworking an existing app and don't want to dig through a bunch of templates)

I need to be able to concat the results of multiple jqlite .find() statements.  It doesn't seem like jqlite supports calls like .find('select,input'). I always get an empty array.  Also, since it returns objects, I cannot just concat them.  I'll probably get a facepalm from this, but I turn to you, StackOverflow.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('disableContents', function() {
    return {
        compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
            var inputs = tElem.find('input');
            var selects = tElem.find('select');

            var formItems = SOMETHINGTOJOINTHESTUFFABOVE
            angular.forEach(formItems, function(el){
...
```

heres what i've come up with so far, but it bugs me to have multiple foreach statements.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('induction').directive('sttiDisabled', function() {
    return {
        compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
            var inputs = tElem.find('input');
            var selects = tElem.find('select');

            var applyDisable = function(el) {
                el = angular.element(el);
                var prevVal = el.attr('ng-disabled');
                prevVal = prevVal? prevVal +  ' || ': '';
                prevVal += tAttrs['sttiDisabled'];
                el.attr('ng-disabled', prevVal);
            }

            angular.forEach(inputs, function(el){
                applyDisable(el);
            });

            angular.forEach(selects, function(el){
                applyDisable(el);
            });


        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jqLite` ([angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)) indeed doesn't support complex selectors so you will have to first select all you need with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) and then wrap this collection with `angular.element` instance:

```
var formControls = angular.element(tElem[0].querySelectorAll('input, select'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Either I didn't quiet understand the question, or the solution is:

```
var formItems = inputs.concat(selects);
```

Comment: I can't concat an object array.  Its not a function of the inputs object The .find() returns an object array, albeit it is almost EXACTLY like a normal array of items.  inputs[0] and inputs[1] both work, but it returns property 1 and property 2, each being one of the elements found.  Its frustrating.

Comment: Yes, you didn't understand the question. `inputs` is not an array so it doesn't have concat method.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll have jQuery referenced before angular.js file you'll get a jQuery object instead of jQLite.. Also remember that jQLite is "Limited to lookups by tag name".

Comment: Angular + Raw jQuery? How dare thee!  All kidding aside, I'm restricted by the project lead from doing this.  Has to be an angular only or javascript only solution.  Thanks though, its an interesting approach.

Comment: Haha. Yeah let's kill one of the good things about angular js and get back to boiler plate javascript DOM manipulation...

Comment: I know enough to be dangerous